# What are windows 7 N/KN/VL editions?

Tags: windows, windows-7

We're subscribed to MSDN at work and I've noticed that among the various windows "editions" there are downloads such as "Windows 7 Ultimate N" and "Windows 7 Ultimate N and KN".

What are these versions and what is the difference between "regular" windows 7 and these version?

Comment: N does not include certain media related technologies (Windows Media Player, Camera, Music, TV & Movies) and does not include the Skype app.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

---

- N is made for the EU market and does not include Windows Media Player.
- KN is made for the Korean Market and does not include Windows Media Player or an Instant Messenger.
- VL are volume license editions for business enterprise customers and uses MAK (Multiple Activation Keys) or KMS (Key Management Server) to activate.

---

Everything else is exactly the same as retail editions except for those changes above.

Comment: Strictly (and this may have changed since you posted 5 years ago!) I believe K is for the Korean market, that simply has to have a couple of website shortcuts. KN includes both K & N amendments i.e includes both the Korean links, and doesn't include media player.

Answer (score 8):

These various editions lack certain built-in features like a media player, web browser, and/or messaging client.  On certain ones, that functionality can be restored through downloads from Microsoft.

The reason for these editions is compliance with terms placed on Microsoft for doing business in the EU as a result of the various antitrust lawsuits brought against the company in Europe.

Comment: Is there a list of the features somewhere?

Comment: Yes.  Basically, K editions do not have Windows Messenger, and N editions do not have Windows Media Player.  Full details can be found on Microsoft's site: Korean Antitrust settlement versions (Windows K and KN editions): http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/Antitrust/KoreanOrder/FAQ.aspx European Antitrust settlement versions (Windows N editions): http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/Antitrust/EUDecision/FAQ.aspx

Comment: I found updated links to the Korean Antitrust Order https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/antitrust/koreanorder/faq.aspx, and the EU Decision https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/antitrust/eudecision/default.aspx